# dgrid 1.2.1 OnDemandGrid not firing request when scrolling

Tags: javascript, dgrid, dstore

I'm using dgrid 1.2.1 OnDemandGrid, and with it have tried both dstore 1.1.1 and 1.1.2 (Rest, SimpleQuery, Trackable).  It seems no matter what I try I am unable to get the virtual scrolling to work.

My store is defined as:

```
seStore = new declare([Rest, SimpleQuery, Trackable])({
    target: appUrl + "api/GET_ITEMS",
    idProperty: "SID",
    sortParam: "sort",
    useRangeHeaders: true  
});
```

Defined with the store is a method for the sorting and filtering:

```
seStore.getSECollection = function (sortFieldName, desc) {
    var sFilter = {};
    if (sArea != "") {
        sFilter.AREA = sArea;
    }
    var coll = seStore.filter(sFilter).sort({ property: sortFieldName, descending: desc });

    return coll;
}
```

Grid:

```
// Create a Grid instance 
seGrid = new (declare([OnDemandGrid, Selection, DijitRegistry, Selector, Keyboard, Editor, ColumnHider, ColumnResizer, ColumnReorder]))({
    id: "seGrid",
    idProperty: "SID",
    cellNavigation: true,
    columns: seColumns,
    collection: seStore.getSECollection("SID", true),
    region: 'center',
    selectionMode: "multiple",
    keepScrollPosition: true,
    query: { responseType: "json" },
    getBeforePut: false,
    farOffRemoval: Infinity, // larger than total height of data; never remove rows
    minRowsPerPage: 25, // request more data at a time
    maxRowsPerPage: 50,
    pagingMethod: 'throttleDelayed',
    queryRowsOverlap: 0,
    //loadingMessage: "Loading data...",
    noDataMessage: "No results found.",
    showFooter: true
});
```

And backend REST service response provides the correct response where rItems is an array of items from my database query and rTotal is the total number of items in the database for this query:

```
HttpResponseMessage rm = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
string dgrJsonResults = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rItems, Formatting.None);
rm.Content = new StringContent(dgrJsonResults, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
rm.Content.Headers.ContentRange = new ContentRangeHeaderValue((long)start, (long)count, rTotal) { Unit = "items" };
```

The grid initally loads correctly with the first 25 items requested, but after this initial request once I scroll down to the bottom (item 25), a request to get the next range of data is not fired.

Can someone please help point me in the right direction?

Comment: I am still having this issue.  It is returning the first 25 records, but when I scroll down it stops and nothing is fired to request the next 25 records.

Comment: Has anyone been able to get this working in dgrid 1.2.1 and dstore 1.1.2?  

I can see via Fiddler that my response header has what seems to be the right content-type and content-range: 

Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Range: items 0-24/225

And that my response is also including a total:

{
  "total": 225,
  "items": [
    {
      "ID": "003414",

When I scroll down I get to row 25 and nothing seems to happen. There are no new requests appearing in Fiddler when I get to the bottom of the first 25 rows.

Comment: I am adding the correct Content-Range header: 

rm.Content.Headers.Add(@"Content-Range", "items " + start.ToString() + "-" + end.ToString() + "/" + rTotal.ToString());

and I am seeing the correct Content-Range header in Fiddler:

Content-Range: items 0-24/225

I understand that it is the OnDemandGrid that is suppose to request more data, but what makes it fire that request??